# How to retain the chat history for the existing conversation id with the BotFramework direct line API 3.0?

Tags: java, json, rest, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I'm trying to display the user's chat history with my bot so that when they come back they can see their previous conversations. When I'm trying to send transcript object to conversationsSendConversationHistory(String conversationId, Transcript history).

I am getting a Forbidden (403) and the user history is not displayed in the chatbot but bot responded details are able to see in webchat.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

I'm using BotFramework SDK v.3 in Java and DirectLine API 3.0

API:https://directline.botframework.com/v3/conversations/1kDMfNnGZhF8N8IbW5gwGy--c/activities/history

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "action": null,
    "attachments": [],
    "attachmentLayout": null,
    "channelData": null,
    "channelId": "webchat",
    "conversation": {
      "id": "Ch3aQxbVKCULecS9Vp7kWm-c",
      "name": null,
      "isGroup": null
    },
    "entities": [],
    "from": {
      "id": "27c3a0d9120607d3969a06a0305a5a7f06645f46c0d5f006337ceca057838350",
      "name": "User"
    },
    "historyDisclosed": null,
    "id": "Ch3aQxbVKCULecS9Vp7kWm-c|20200207-141252-1",
    "locale": null,
    "localTimestamp": "2020-02-07T13:38:15.674Z",
    "membersAdded": [],
    "membersRemoved": [],
    "name": null,
    "recipient": {
      "id": "demobot-dev-de-dev@VeY8HxuBVIw",
      "name": "Demobot DEV DE"
    },
    "relatesTo": null,
    "replyToId": "Ch3aQxbVKCULecS9Vp7kWm-c|0000005",
    "serviceUrl": "https://directline.botframework.com/",
    "suggestedActions": null,
    "summary": null,
    "text": "USER- Hi",
    "textFormat": null,
    "timestamp": "2020-02-07T13:38:15.674Z",
    "topicName": null,
    "type": "message",
    "speak": "USER- Hi",
    "value": null,
    "event": false,
    "message": true,
    "tenantEvent": false
  },
  {
    "action": null,
    "attachments": [],
    "attachmentLayout": null,
    "channelData": null,
    "channelId": "webchat",
    "conversation": {
      "id": "Ch3aQxbVKCULecS9Vp7kWm-c",
      "name": null,
      "isGroup": null
    },
    "entities": [],
    "from": {
      "id": "demobot-dev-de-dev@VeY8HxuBVIw",
      "name": "Demobot DEV DE"
    },
    "historyDisclosed": null,
    "id": "Ch3aQxbVKCULecS9Vp7kWm-c|20200207-141252-2",
    "locale": null,
    "localTimestamp": "2020-02-07T13:38:15.687Z",
    "membersAdded": [],
    "membersRemoved": [],
    "name": null,
    "recipient": {
      "id": "27c3a0d9120607d3969a06a0305a5a7f06645f46c0d5f006337ceca057838350",
      "name": "User"
    },
    "relatesTo": null,
    "replyToId": "Ch3aQxbVKCULecS9Vp7kWm-c|0000001",
    "serviceUrl": "https://directline.botframework.com",
    "suggestedActions": null,
    "summary": null,
    "text": "BOT- Hallo ich bin der <b>DemoBot</b> und <a href=\"www.gmail.com\">zeige</a> dir die Plattform Features. Einfach auf eins der Quickreplies klicken und los geht's! Ach so... Und falls ich dich mal nicht verstehe wäre es schön, mich nachzutrainieren.",
    "textFormat": null,
    "timestamp": "2020-02-07T13:38:15.687Z",
    "topicName": null,
    "type": "message",
    "speak": "BOT- Hallo ich bin der <b>DemoBot</b> und <a href=\"www.gmail.com\">zeige</a> dir die Plattform Features. Einfach auf eins der Quickreplies klicken und los geht's! Ach so... Und falls ich dich mal nicht verstehe wäre es schön, mich nachzutrainieren.",
    "value": null,
    "event": false,
    "message": true,
    "tenantEvent": false
  },
  {
    "action": null,
    "attachments": [],
    "attachmentLayout": null,
    "channelData": null,
    "channelId": "webchat",
    "conversation": {
      "id": "Ch3aQxbVKCULecS9Vp7kWm-c",
      "name": null,
      "isGroup": null
    },
    "entities": [],
    "from": {
      "id": "27c3a0d9120607d3969a06a0305a5a7f06645f46c0d5f006337ceca057838350",
      "name": "User"
    },
    "historyDisclosed": null,
    "id": "Ch3aQxbVKCULecS9Vp7kWm-c|20200207-141252-3",
    "locale": null,
    "localTimestamp": "2020-02-07T14:12:42.638Z",
    "membersAdded": [],
    "membersRemoved": [],
    "name": null,
    "recipient": {
      "id": "demobot-dev-de-dev@VeY8HxuBVIw",
      "name": "Demobot DEV DE"
    },
    "relatesTo": null,
    "replyToId": "Ch3aQxbVKCULecS9Vp7kWm-c|0000005",
    "serviceUrl": "https://directline.botframework.com/",
    "suggestedActions": null,
    "summary": null,
    "text": "USER- I want to book the tickets",
    "textFormat": null,
    "timestamp": "2020-02-07T14:12:42.638Z",
    "topicName": null,
    "type": "message",
    "speak": "USER- I want to book the tickets",
    "value": null,
    "event": false,
    "message": true,
    "tenantEvent": false
  },
  {
    "action": null,
    "attachments": [],
    "attachmentLayout": null,
    "channelData": null,
    "channelId": "webchat",
    "conversation": {
      "id": "Ch3aQxbVKCULecS9Vp7kWm-c",
      "name": null,
      "isGroup": null
    },
    "entities": [],
    "from": {
      "id": "demobot-dev-de-dev@VeY8HxuBVIw",
      "name": "Demobot DEV DE"
    },
    "historyDisclosed": null,
    "id": "Ch3aQxbVKCULecS9Vp7kWm-c|20200207-141252-4",
    "locale": null,
    "localTimestamp": "2020-02-07T14:12:42.676Z",
    "membersAdded": [],
    "membersRemoved": [],
    "name": null,
    "recipient": {
      "id": "27c3a0d9120607d3969a06a0305a5a7f06645f46c0d5f006337ceca057838350",
      "name": "User"
    },
    "relatesTo": null,
    "replyToId": "Ch3aQxbVKCULecS9Vp7kWm-c|0000003",
    "serviceUrl": "https://directline.botframework.com",
    "suggestedActions": null,
    "summary": null,
    "text": "BOT- Darauf habe ich leider keine Antwort. Versuche es doch bitte mit einer anderen Formulierung",
    "textFormat": null,
    "timestamp": "2020-02-07T14:12:42.676Z",
    "topicName": null,
    "type": "message",
    "speak": "BOT- Darauf habe ich leider keine Antwort. Versuche es doch bitte mit einer anderen Formulierung",
    "value": null,
    "event": false,
    "message": true,
    "tenantEvent": false
  }
]
```

Code:

```
public void uploadChatHistroy(final String accessToken, final Activity activity, final List<Activity> history) {
    Transcript transcript = new Transcript();
    final String basePath = removeLastSlash(activity.getServiceUrl());
    final String conversationId = activity.getConversation().getId();
    Integer incrementId = 0;
    try {
        for (Activity activityHistory : history) {  
            incrementId++;
            activityHistory.setId(getRandomIdFromDate(conversationId) + incrementId);
            activityHistory.setChannelData(null);
            activityHistory.setServiceUrl(basePath);
            ConversationAccount conversation = new ConversationAccount();
            conversation.setId(activity.getConversation().getId());
            activityHistory.setConversation(conversation);

            if (activity.getFrom().getId().equals(activityHistory.getFrom().getId())) {
                // If the activity was from the user, assign the bot as the recipient
                activityHistory.setReplyToId(activity.getId());
                activityHistory.setFrom(activity.getFrom());
                activityHistory.setRecipient(activity.getRecipient());
            } else if (activity.getFrom().getId().equals(activityHistory.getRecipient().getId())) {
                // If the activity was from the bot, assign the user as the recipient

                activityHistory.setFrom(activity.getRecipient());
                activityHistory.setRecipient(activity.getFrom());
                activityHistory.setText("BOT- " + activityHistory.getText());
            }
            else {
                activityHistory.setFrom(activity.getRecipient());
                activityHistory.setRecipient(activity.getFrom());
                activityHistory.setText("BOT- " + activityHistory.getText());
            }

        }
        transcript.setActivities(history);

        getConversationsApi(accessToken, basePath).conversationsSendConversationHistory(conversationId, transcript);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("getConversationsApi: {} ", e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Exception:

```
channel.msbotframework.api.client.ApiException: Forbidden  
    at channel.msbotframework.api.client.ApiClient.handleResponse(ApiClient.java:951)  
    at channel.msbotframework.api.client.ApiClient.execute(ApiClient.java:867)  
    at channel.msbotframework.api.ConversationsApi.conversationsSendConversationHistoryWithHttpInfo(ConversationsApi.java:1192)  
    at channel.msbotframework.api.ConversationsApi.conversationsSendConversationHistory(ConversationsApi.java:1176)
```

My application flow:

1. Check if there is any conversation stored session or not.
2. If the conversation is present in the session reconnect using that conversation ID
3. Send an event to the backend application to restore the history
4. Fetch the previous activities from the database and create the Transcript object
5. Call conversationsSendConversationHistory(conversationId, transcript) internally it's sending to the direct line API.

Here I am getting the forbidden always while pushing user details.

I can chat with the bot even if this fails using the old conversation ID. I also tried to make the bot do a ReplyToActivity and this works.

Does anybody know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You seem to have omitted quotation marks from your sample transcript, so it will be hard to know where you problem is since we're not looking at the actual objects you used. Can you go ahead and post a sample transcript as JSON so we can try it out with the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference) in Postman?

Comment: @KyleDelaney: I have attached the JSON file and the issue is unable to display user details in the webchat but same implementation is working in emulator.

Comment: Thanks for the new information. May I ask why you've changed your error code from 400 bad request to 403 forbidden? Also, there is no Bot Framework v3 SDK in Java. The Java SDK is only in v4. Did you mean you're using Bot Builder v4? Also, is the Java code you provided in your bot or in your Direct Line client?

Comment: @KyleDelaney: Thank you very much for providing your valuable time to check this issue. Initially, I was getting 400 error after that I changed from and recipients details and tested now I am getting 403 only for user details and not for the responded details. I mean now I am able to see bot responded details in the webchat. I have generated the client from https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/swagger/ConnectorAPI.json.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "user details" and "bot responded details." What details are you talking about? Do you mean the SendConversationHistory API call is succeeding when you leave the user-to-bot messages out of your transcript?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I Can explain to you using one example.

Comment: 1. Suppose the customer typed 'Hi' in the webchat and for this bot responded with 'Hello, How can I help you today?'
2. Using these details, I am preparing the activities list and passing to the SendConversationHistory API as a transcript.

Comment: So when you say details, you mean activities?

Comment: Yes, If you observe the above activites list first activity contains a user typed message and the second activity contains bot response for the first activity.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. I've run your code using your activity JSON and it sends the conversation history just fine. One difference may be that I don't know how you generate your conversations API so I just grabbed mine from the turn context. It looks like you're using a token. Can you try doing something like this? `ConnectorClient connectorClient = context.getTurnState().get("ConnectorClient");`

Comment: I am generating the ConversationsAPI using APIClient like below:
OAuth2AccessToken token = oAuth2.getAccessToken(botId);                                     
protected ConversationsApi getConversationsApi(final String accessToken, final String basePath) {
  final ApiClient apiClient = getApiClient(accessToken, basePath);
  return new ConversationsApi(apiClient);
 }

Comment: Please do not post multiple lines of code in comments. Can you see how difficult it is to read now that you've posted it? If you want to post multiple lines of code then you should edit the code into your question. I posted code in a comment because it was just one line and I used backticks to format it. Anyway, I think I see now that you are running this code from your Direct Line client and not from your bot. If you don't want to access the transcript from your bot, can you link to the Java Direct Line SDK you're using and any tutorials/documentation you followed? I haven't seen this before.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience and I will try and let you know the status

Comment: Can you link to the Java Direct Line SDK you're using and any tutorials/documentation you followed?

Comment: Are you still working on this?